# How to access docker container's shell from a remote machine

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu, console

A docker container is running in a headless Ubuntu machine. We are looking to access the shell of the docker from a remote machine connected to the LAN of the host Ubuntu machine. SSH is not an option since the docker image that we want to run does not support SSH.

I can access the docker shell with `docker exec -it /bin/sh`. How can I do similar shell access from a remote host?

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that docker doesn't support SSH? Please cite some resources which mentions this.

Comment: SSH into the host machine and do `docker exec -it ...`

Comment: The docker image that I want to run doesn't have SSH and dont have any package managers to install it. It has a limited shell. @kiner_shah

Comment: @HansKilian We are doing that now. So there is no way to get the shell in a remote machine?

Comment: Like Aleksey says, you can expose the docker port on the host and use docker context to switch which docker daemon you talk to. You can also run sshd inside the container, but running 2 processes in the container feels like a cludge. I prefer ssh'ing to the host.

Answer (score -2):

To connect to the remote docker engine you should follow [instruction](https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/11/28/connect-your-docker-client-to-a-remote-docker-host/).